# Quasar\Vue: Unexpected mutation of "amountValue" prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar

I'm new to vue, I get this error

Unexpected mutation of "amountValue" prop.

What am I wrong with it?

```html
  <q-input v-model="amountValue"></q-input>

<script>


export default defineComponent({
  ...
  props: {
    amountValue: Number
  },
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const amount = computed({
      get: () => props.amountValue,
      set: (value) => {
        emit("update:amountValue", value)
      },
    })

...
  },
})
</script>
```

Comment: Also make sure to pass to the prop to the child like so: `<child-component v-model="amountValue" />`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `amount` computed property instead of `amountValue` prop, as `v-model` will change the value of the `amountValue` prop directly in the child component which generates this warning.

```
  <q-input v-model="amount"></q-input>
```